# Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

The code provided below doesn't show all the content of that page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname
alert(rootdomain);
function ajaxinclude(url) {
var url=rootdomain+url;
var page_request = false
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
try {
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
} 
catch (e){
try{
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
catch (e){}
}
}
else
return false
page_request.open('GET', url, false) //get page synchronously 
page_request.send(null)
writecontent(page_request)
}

function writecontent(page_request){
if (window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1 || 
page_request.status==200)
document.getElementById("write").innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="write">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Submit !" onclick="ajaxinclude('/songcake/index.php');"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Please Help

Thanks.

Comment: Please highlight your code in edit view and click the "code" button to format it as code.

Comment: i think you have to include prototype.js if you not using jquery

Comment: @Salil - Prototype is another option that would also make this easier, its by no means required though

Comment: @ rajesh: please either accept an answer or post another comment in case you still have trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a closure that reacts upon the completion of the document loading process.

```
page_request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(page_request.readystate == 4) { 
        // data handling here
    } 
}
```

As pointed out though, using jQuery will make things a lot easier.

Edit: To clarify, your AJAX call does check for the connection status (`request.status`), but not for the loading status (`request.readystate`). Your document probably did not load completely. 
Here's a reference for the W3.org XMLHTTPRequest API: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/ .

Edit2: Btw, an `<iframe>` element would solve your problem with a lot less code.

Edit 3: Code

```
function ajaxinclude(url) {
    //...
    page_request.open('GET', url, false) //get page synchronously 
    //<> add onreadystatechange handler
    page_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(page_request.readystate === 4) {
            if(page_request.state === 200) {
               //call function on success
                   writecontent(page_request.responseXML)
            }
        }
    }
    page_request.send(null)
}
```

Some additions:

1. if you put your ajax call into the `<HEAD>` you need to either create the dom elements you want to append data to as they are not available when the runtime runs through (which might lead to a dom error); or you need to add an on dom load event handler.
2. Synchronous calls are not properly implemented in some browsers and this might lead to errors too.

Comment: actually i don't want to use iframe ,i know use of iframe is very but i actually want to use div so please give suggestion regarding code.....

Comment: I suggest, loding from Ajax into the same frame is better than IFrame.

Comment: @ Muneer: I said less code, not better solution. In other words, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Why you should not use jQuery? You can do this simple as below..

```
$("#write").load("/songcake/index.php");
```

[EDITED]

Below you can see the completed code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src='scripts/jquery.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="write">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Submit !" 
   onclick="$('#write').load('/songcake/index.php');"/>

</body>
</html>
```

You can download jQuery from here : http://jquery.com/
The source for my answer you can find here : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: thanks for the reply
But please will u send the complete code.

Comment: or indeed any other JavaScript library

Answer (score 0):

try to use FireBug

FireBug show you state of your request.
If it 200 and you see that in reqest answer (in firebug) broken data  then 
you should check your **index.php** script